# How does this C code work?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I was looking at the following code I came across for printing a string in reverse order in C using recursion:

```
void ReversePrint(char *str) { //line 1
  if(*str) {                   //line 2
      ReversePrint(str+1);     //line 3
      putchar(*str);           //line 4
  }
}
```

I am relatively new to C and am confused by line 2. `*str` from my understanding is dereferencing the pointer and should return the value of the string in the current position.  But how is this being used as an argument to a conditional statement (which should except a boolean right?)?  In line 3, the pointer will always be incremented to the next block (4 bytes since its an int)...so couldn't this code fail if there happens to be data in the next memory block after the end of the string?

**Update**: so there are no boolean types in c correct? A conditional statement evaluates to 'false' if the value is 0, and 'true' otherwise?

Comment: Boy, I hope that wasn't production code! :)

Comment: Wonder how long a string would have to be before it explooodes.

Comment: Probably very long... but still.

Comment: Originally the method was called StrReverse4, so possibly it was intended for strings of about 4 chars in length.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Line 2 is checking to see if the current character is the null terminator of the string - since C strings are null-terminated, and the null character is considered a false value, it will begin unrolling the recursion when it hits the end of the string (instead of trying to call StrReverse4 on the character after the null terminator, which would be beyond the bounds of the valid data).

Also note that the pointer is to a `char`, thus incrementing the pointer only increments by 1 byte (since `char` is a single-byte type).

Example:

```
 0  1  2  3
+--+--+--+--+
|f |o |o |\0|
+--+--+--+--+
```

1. When `str` = `0`, then `*str` is `'f'` so the recursive call is made for str+1 = 1.
2. When `str` = `1`, then `*str` is `'o'` so the recursive call is made for str+1 = 2.
3. When `str` = `2`, then `*str` is `'o'` so the recursive call is made for str+1 = 3.
4. When `str` = `3`, then `*str` is `'\0'` and `\0` is a false value thus `if(*str)` evaluates to false, so no recursive call is made, thus going back up the recursion we get...
5. Most recent recursion was followed by `putchar('o'), then after that,
6. Next most recent recursion was followed by `putchar('o'), then after that,
7. Least recent recursion was followed by `putchar('f'), and we're done.

Comment: thanks for the response..but as mentioned in my update..can you elaborate on what is meant by 'null is considered a false value' since c doesn't have a boolean type?

Comment: In C, there is no boolean type, correct - instead, logic statements simply treat anything that evaluates to 0 as `false`, and anything which evaluates to non-zero as `true`. Since the "null character" is actually just a byte whose value is 0, it is considered `false`.

Comment: Minor critique - the ASCII character 0 is usually referred to as "nul" (with one l), while the invalid pointer is usually referred to as "NULL" (with two l's). I think it's important to make a distinction here, because it's easy to get lost with pointers.

Comment: "nul" is a short form, yes, however when speaking of "null terminator" or "null character" usually the proper spelling (with two l's) is used. For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character

Comment: Wikipedia, by our (WP's) own terms, is not to be used for references.  In the case of this Null_character article, it is a source of disinformation.  User:HeathHunnicutt

Comment: I've seen nothing on Wikipedia which indicates that such is any more than your own opinion, Heath.

Comment: @Heath - Wikipedia disagrees with you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:Citing_Wikipedia

Comment: @Amber: In C there is a Boolean type, `_Bool`.

Comment: @dreamlax: Only in C99 and later.

Comment: @Amber: C99 is C, just as much as C++98 (or maybe even C++03) is C++.

Comment: @dreamlax: Yes, C99 is C, but C is not necessarily C99.

Answer (score 3):

The type of a C string is nothing but a pointer to char. The convention is that what the pointer points to is an array of characters, *terminated by a zero byte*.

`*str`, thus, is the first character of the string pointed to by `str`.

Using `*str` in a conditional evaluates to `false` if `str` points to the terminating null byte in the (empty) string.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of a string is typically a 0 byte - the line `if (*str)` is checking for the existence of that byte and stopping when it gets to it.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the string there is a `0` - so you have `"test" => [0]'t' [1]'e' [2]'s' [3]'t' [4]0`

and `if(0) -> false`

this way this will work.

Answer (score 1):

> In line 3, the pointer will always be incremented to the next block (4 bytes since its an int)...

Thats wrong, this is char *, it will only be incremented by 1. Because char is 1 byte long only.

> But how is this being used as an argument to a conditional statement (which should except a boolean right?)?

You can use any value in if( $$ ) at $$, and it will only check if its non zero or not, basically bool is also implemented as simple 1=true and 0=false only.

In other higher level strongly typed language you cant use such things in if, but in C everything boils down to numbers. And you can use anything.

```
if(1) // evaluates to true 
if("string")  // evaluates to true
if(0) // evaulates to false
```

You can give any thing in if,while conditions in C.

Answer (score 0):

conditional statements (`if`, `for`, `while`, etc) expect a boolean expression. If you provide an integer value the evaluation boils down to `0 == false` or `non-0 == true`. As mentioned already, the terminating character of a c-string is a null byte (integer value 0). So the `if` will fail at the end of the string (or first null byte within the string).

As an aside, if you do `*str` on a NULL pointer you are invoking undefined behavior; you should always verify that a pointer is valid before dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

1.

`str` is a pointer to a char. Incrementing `str` will make the pointer point to the second character of the string (as it's a char array). 
NOTE: Incrementing pointers will increment by the data type the pointer points to.

For ex:

```
int *p_int;
p_int++;     /* Increments by 4 */

double *p_dbl;
p_dbl++;      /* Increments by 8 */
```

2.

```
if(expression)
{
   statements;
}
```

The expression is evaluated and if the resulting value is zero (`NULL`, `\0`, `0`), the statements are not executed. As every string ends with `\0` the recursion will have to end some time.

Comment: Not every string is guaranteed to end in a null byte. Indeed, most times it is; but there is nothing that requires this to be the case.

Comment: Agree. I just assumed this in this case.

Comment: @ezpz: a C-string is *by definition* a sequence of characters terminated by a null-character; if there's no terminating null, it's just not a C-string ;)

Answer (score 0):

C has no concept of boolean values: in C, every scalar type (ie arithmetic and pointer types) can be used in boolean contexts where `0` means `false` and non-zero `true`.

As strings are null-terminated, the terminator will be interpreted as `false`, whereas every other character (with non-zero value!) will be `true`. This means means there's an easy way to iterate over the characters of a string:

```
for(;*str; ++str) { /* so something with *str */ }
```

`StrReverse4()` does the same thing, but by recursion instead of iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, which is as simple as the one which you are using:

```
int rev(int lower,int upper,char*string)
{
  if(lower>upper)
          return 0;
   else
          return rev(lower-1,upper-1,string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of off topic, but when I saw the question I immediately wondered if that was actually faster than just doing an strlen and iterate from the back.

So, I made a little test.

```
#include <string.h>

void reverse1(const char* str)
{
    int total = 0;
    if (*str) {
            reverse1(str+1);
            total += *str;
    }
}

void reverse2(const char* str)
{
    int total = 0;
    size_t t = strlen(str);
    while (t > 0) {
            total += str[--t];
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* str = "here I put a very long string ...";

    int i=99999;

    while (--i > 0) reverseX(str);
}
```

I first compiled it with X=1 (using the function reverse1) and then with X=2. Both times with -O0.

It consistently returned approximately 6 seconds for the recursive version and 1.8 seconds for the strlen version.

I think it's because strlen is implemented in assembler and the recursion adds quite an overhead.

I'm quite sure that the benchmark is representative, if I'm mistaken please correct me.

Anyway, I thought I should share this with you.

Comment: It's probably because *in your system* the overhead for the recursive function calls is large compared to the time of the iterative solution, which makes ONE function call to strlen.  

My main point is making generalizations from one test can be dangerous, if interesting.  It's better to write clear, maintainable code first and optimize it later, only when actual performance testing reveals bottlenecks.

Comment: I agree. Although, as strlen scans linearly (I guess) all the string, the comparison should be between one function call (the recursion) and one iteration of the strlen implementation plus 1/n of the strlen function call. But, again, I agree that it's better to write clear and then optimize if needed. A question, in your system it's faster the recursion solution rather than the iterative solution?